# Is there a better way than using forceUpdate for this

Tags: reactjs

I am just curious if this is an ok use of forceUpdate or if there is a better way to achieve this since [forceUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) is discouraged.  I have a component that renders a name property and needs it to be editable so users can rename the feature, however the name property is stored outside of Flux or React because it is part of the Esri JavaScript API graphics layers.  For example, I have a feature in my graphics layer whose JSON looks like this:

```
feature = {
  attributes: {
    Name: 'Custom Drawn Feature',
    __source: 'draw_toolbar'
  },
  geometry: {...},
  ...
}
```

Currently I have a component whose render function returns something like this:

```
<div className='custom-feature__header'>
  <input className='custom-feature__input' type='text' value={feature.attributes.Name} onChange={this.editName} />
  <div className='custom-feature__delete pointer' onClick={this.deleteFeature}>{text[language].DELETE}</div>
</div>
```

And an editName function that updates the name like so:

```
editName = ({target}) => {
  const {feature} = this.props;
  feature.attributes.Name = target.value;
  this.forceUpdate();
};
```

I don't want to set the name to state as that feels a bit like an anti-pattern to take props and set it to state, plus now I don't have a single source of truth since the name exists in a component (which is used in multiple places in the UI) and in the feature attributes in the graphics layer.

I also tried setting `defaultValue` instead of `value` and then not calling forceUpdate which worked really well, except that other places in the UI using this component did not reflect the change until they were remounted. Which I suspect happens because the props object did not change, its the same feature with an updated property.

Immutable would be nice but the data model is not controlled by me, it is provided by the Esri JavaScript API and I don't want to store duplicate data.

So back to the original question, is this one of those cases that is acceptable to use `forceUpdate` or would it be better to store a `key` value (maybe like Math.random()) in state that I change every time the name is edited, or is their another better way?

EDIT:
Just to clarify, the feature is stored in an Esri Graphic's Layer. These components are just rendering the state of the map and the only way to update the name of a graphic is by changing it's attributes directly, via `feature.attributes.Name = 'New Name'`.  This needs to be done so other Esri API methods and widgets can display/use it properly, like popup windows and search widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation and setup I understand that:

- the only way to tell the world outside the component that `feature.attribute.Name` needs a new name, is to mutate this prop.
- because your component will NOT be re-rendered by any parent with new props, you use the `forceUpdate()` to trigger re-render.

Although react sort of allows the use of `forceUpdate()` for this purpose ([see docs here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate)), by naming following as a reason to use it:

> (eg: data deep within an object changes without changing the object
>   itself)

I still think **putting `feature.attribute.name` in state is a better and cleaner solution**.

Putting this prop in state in this way is **not** an anti-pattern.  Official docs on [props in initialstate here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html), explain that it is perfectly valid to put props in ***initial*** state for the purpose of having the component update state.

> However, it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that the prop
>   is only seed data for the component's internally-controlled state

A stateful solution would look something like:

```
const newName = target.value;
this.props.feature.attributes.Name = newName; // inform outside world of new name
this.setState( { name: newName });
```

Putting the name in state makes it much more clear that:

- the prop `feature.attribute.name` is passed in as an initial prop only
- your component may change the name in state, causing the component to re-render.
- the value in the DOM and in state are always in sync
- make it very explicit that you are directly mutating a prop and why

PS: There is a slight difference technically between the `forceUpdate()` and the stateful approach:

- `forceUpdate()` will skip any `shouldComponentUpdate()` (the DOM diff engine will still prevent update if newname == previousname)

Comment: `forceUpdate` is actually working right now, it was the only thing that did.  I was thinking of putting it in state but then I have to update state and update the feature on the Graphics Layer, and the only way to update the feature on the Graphics layer is by doing `feature.attributes.name = 'New Name'`, so I have to change it that way.  I am not condoning mutating props but that is the only way to change the features name since it is coming from Esri's Graphic Layer and not a store, if it were a store, then I would Flux it.

Comment: Plus isn't taking state and saving it as props an anti-pattern that we are also supposed to avoid. See here https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: Sorry, just realized I read that wrong ,Yes it only works with `forceUpdate`, thought you wrote it does not work WITH `forceUpdate`.  I tested another way of editing it which may be better but requires much more code.  The feature is from a graphics layer which is from the Esri Map Object, I can get the map, get the layer, find the graphic and update it there and then run an action from the top which will rerender these as well, but, it would still have to edit it via `feature.attributes.Name = 'New Name` so not sure if that approach is worth it.

Comment: Edited my answer with further update. Summary: I understand that directly mutating props is the only way. My advise: make prop update very explicit, and do use state inside the component to make the workings more transparent.

Comment: Ok I see, that makes sense.  Still update the maps state by editing the feature but use its name as initial state for the component.  Thanks for the explanation, it was very helpful